# making un-visible a specific part of url generated by javascript + codeigniter

Tags: javascript, url, codeigniter, seo, gallery

http://www.blabla.com/our_work/client/client-name#/uploads/18.jpg

I use CodeIgniter, and this is the url I have.  I use a gallery script at the page, and it generates #/uploads/18.jpg such thing at url :( is there any way to make it unvisible or sth . maybe with htaccess. i dont know.

i dont want to spend an another day finding an another gallery script, im already out of deadline :(

appreciate helps...

Answer (score 1):

Just leave it there. What's the harm? Really. You are on a deadline, and are wasting time trying to remove a #tag from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Can we have a look at the gallery script? perhaps you could edit something there to make it work. That's what I always do with the scripts I use to make them work with CI.

Comment: it is this script;
http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/demo_01.htm#img/grass-blades.jpg

i researched but nobody complains about such url :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's how it's supposed to work. the '#' part is an HTML anchor that the script uses to do the switching as far as I know. You might to look for a different script.

Comment: at least if I can clear the path somehow, that is fine. also keeping same path. like this: client/client-name#18.jpg

Comment: Then perhaps make all the images in the same directory, since the script apparently takes the value of an <img> "src".

Answer (score 0):

you can try to play with window.location in JS erasing the string after hash, but I doubt that would make some sense.